# Are DBeaver/PostgreSQL Datatype = Polygon real PostGIS spatial Objects?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, dbeaver

I am currently designing a database for my PhD-Project. I want to link a PostgreSQL database to QGIS. I just started in PostgreSQL and am using DBeaver 6.2.2.

When creating my first Test-DB I saw, that I have a multitude of datatype to chose from for a new column, including Polygon, Point and Line. Does that mean I can create a column with this datatype and store my GIS-Geometries in there and is that already a fully functional PostGIS datatype, that is to say could I create e. g. polygons in QGIS from this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`polygon`,`point` and `line` are native Postgres [data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html) that are not used by PostGIS and have very limited supporting functions.

Instead, you will want to use the `geometry` type, which can be refined to contain only polygons `geometry(polygon)` or even for a specific projection (`geometry(polygon,4326)`)

Comment: Thanks, that clears that up. There appears to be no data type ```geometry``` in the DBeaver drop down. How do I add a column with this data type?

Comment: @C.-F.Vintar make sure you have enabled PostGIS in the DB you are using (`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA public;`)

Comment: I added the extension in DBeaver. In code this is written here as:
```CREATE EXTENSION postgis
 SCHEMA "public"
 VERSION 2.5.3
``` with the Condition ```{"WHERE NOT (
srid BETWEEN 2000 AND 2180
OR srid BETWEEN 2188 AND 2217 [...]``` Apparently that did not work. Perhaps this is a question for a different thread?

Comment: @C.-F.Vintar Yes, make it a new question with lots of details. You shouldn't have to put conditions and so much specifications to enable PostGIS. Only `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` is required.

Comment: This question is now in the following thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344701/how-do-i-add-the-postgis-extension-to-a-postgresql-data-base-in-dbeaver