# How do I check if the PostGIS extension to a PostgreSQL data base is working in DBeaver?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, dbeaver

I am starting with PostgreSQL and trying out a few things in a small testing DB-server. I have connected this DB DBeaver 6.2.2 and added a few tables and columns. Now I wanted to get some spatial data into the DB and used the DBeaver extension manager to install postgis.

In the extension manager this looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of the Extension View in DBeaver 6.2.2 with postgis installed]

The extension is also apparently linked to the DB *postgres* as shown here:
[image: Screenshot of the extension installed to the DB.]

However, I do not have any PostGIS-Features (e. g. the data type *geometry*) available in the new DB. Also the code looks normal enough:

`````
-- DROP EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE EXTENSION postgis
    SCHEMA "public"
    VERSION 2.5.3
    ```
But it comes with a very long list of conditions, which I did not put there, but wich I also can not alter (see below). How do I fix this?

```{"WHERE NOT (
srid BETWEEN 2000 AND 2180
OR srid BETWEEN 2188 AND 2217
OR srid BETWEEN 2219 AND 2220
OR srid BETWEEN 2222 AND 2292
OR srid BETWEEN 2294 AND 2295
OR srid BETWEEN 2308 AND 2962
OR srid BETWEEN 2964 AND 2973
OR srid BETWEEN 2975 AND 2984
OR srid BETWEEN 2987 AND 3051
OR srid BETWEEN 3054 AND 3138
OR srid BETWEEN 3140 AND 3143
OR srid BETWEEN 3146 AND 3172
OR srid BETWEEN 3174 AND 3294
OR srid BETWEEN 3296 AND 3791
OR srid BETWEEN 3793 AND 3802
OR srid = 3812
OR srid BETWEEN 3814 AND 3816
OR srid = 3819
OR srid BETWEEN 3821 AND 3822
OR srid BETWEEN 3824 AND 3829
OR srid BETWEEN 3832 AND 3852
OR srid = 3854
OR srid = 3857
OR srid BETWEEN 3873 AND 3885
OR srid = 3887
OR srid BETWEEN 3889 AND 3893
OR srid BETWEEN 3901 AND 3903
OR srid BETWEEN 3906 AND 3912
OR srid = 3920
OR srid BETWEEN 3942 AND 3950
OR srid BETWEEN 3968 AND 3970
OR srid BETWEEN 3973 AND 3976
OR srid BETWEEN 3978 AND 3979
OR srid BETWEEN 3985 AND 3989
OR srid BETWEEN 3991 AND 3992
OR srid BETWEEN 3994 AND 3997
OR srid BETWEEN 4000 AND 4016
OR srid BETWEEN 4018 AND 4039
OR srid BETWEEN 4041 AND 4063
OR srid = 4071
OR srid = 4073
OR srid = 4075
OR srid = 4079
OR srid BETWEEN 4081 AND 4083
OR srid BETWEEN 4087 AND 4088
OR srid BETWEEN 4093 AND 4100
OR srid BETWEEN 4120 AND 4176
OR srid BETWEEN 4178 AND 4185
OR srid BETWEEN 4188 AND 4289
OR srid BETWEEN 4291 AND 4304
OR srid BETWEEN 4306 AND 4319
OR srid = 4322
OR srid = 4324
OR srid = 4326
OR srid = 4328
OR srid BETWEEN 4330 AND 4338
OR srid = 4340
OR srid = 4342
OR srid = 4344
OR srid = 4346
OR srid = 4348
OR srid = 4350
OR srid = 4352
OR srid = 4354
OR srid = 4356
OR srid = 4358
OR srid = 4360
OR srid = 4362
OR srid = 4364
OR srid = 4366
OR srid = 4368
OR srid = 4370
OR srid = 4372
OR srid = 4374
OR srid = 4376
OR srid = 4378
OR srid = 4380
OR srid = 4382
OR srid BETWEEN 4384 AND 4385
OR srid = 4387
OR srid BETWEEN 4389 AND 4415
OR srid BETWEEN 4417 AND 4434
OR srid BETWEEN 4437 AND 4439
OR srid BETWEEN 4455 AND 4457
OR srid BETWEEN 4462 AND 4463
OR srid = 4465
OR srid BETWEEN 4467 AND 4468
OR srid BETWEEN 4470 AND 4471
OR srid BETWEEN 4473 AND 4475
OR srid = 4479
OR srid = 4481
OR srid BETWEEN 4483 AND 4556
OR srid BETWEEN 4558 AND 4559
OR srid BETWEEN 4568 AND 4589
OR srid BETWEEN 4600 AND 4647
OR srid BETWEEN 4652 AND 4824
OR srid = 4826
OR srid = 4839
OR srid BETWEEN 4855 AND 4880
OR srid = 4882
OR srid = 4884
OR srid = 4886
OR srid = 4888
OR srid = 4890
OR srid = 4892
OR srid = 4894
OR srid BETWEEN 4896 AND 4897
OR srid = 4899
OR srid BETWEEN 4901 AND 4904
OR srid = 4906
OR srid = 4908
OR srid BETWEEN 4910 AND 4920
OR srid = 4922
OR srid = 4924
OR srid = 4926
OR srid = 4928
OR srid = 4930
OR srid = 4932
OR srid = 4934
OR srid = 4936
OR srid = 4938
OR srid = 4940
OR srid = 4942
OR srid = 4944
OR srid = 4946
OR srid = 4948
OR srid = 4950
OR srid = 4952
OR srid = 4954
OR srid = 4956
OR srid = 4958
OR srid = 4960
OR srid = 4962
OR srid = 4964
OR srid = 4966
OR srid = 4968
OR srid = 4970
OR srid = 4972
OR srid = 4974
OR srid = 4976
OR srid = 4978
OR srid = 4980
OR srid = 4982
OR srid = 4984
OR srid = 4986
OR srid = 4988
OR srid = 4990
OR srid = 4992
OR srid = 4994
OR srid = 4996
OR srid = 4998
OR srid = 5011
OR srid BETWEEN 5013 AND 5016
OR srid = 5018
OR srid BETWEEN 5041 AND 5042
OR srid = 5048
OR srid BETWEEN 5069 AND 5072
OR srid BETWEEN 5105 AND 5130
OR srid = 5132
OR srid BETWEEN 5167 AND 5188
OR srid = 5221
OR srid = 5223
OR srid BETWEEN 5228 AND 5229
OR srid BETWEEN 5233 AND 5235
OR srid BETWEEN 5243 AND 5244
OR srid BETWEEN 5246 AND 5247
OR srid = 5250
OR srid BETWEEN 5252 AND 5259
OR srid = 5262
OR srid = 5264
OR srid = 5266
OR srid BETWEEN 5269 AND 5275
OR srid BETWEEN 5292 AND 5311
OR srid = 5316
OR srid = 5318
OR srid BETWEEN 5320 AND 5322
OR srid BETWEEN 5324 AND 5325
OR srid BETWEEN 5329 AND 5332
OR srid = 5337
OR srid BETWEEN 5340 AND 5341
OR srid BETWEEN 5343 AND 5349
OR srid = 5352
OR srid BETWEEN 5354 AND 5358
OR srid BETWEEN 5360 AND 5363
OR srid = 5365
OR srid BETWEEN 5367 AND 5369
OR srid = 5371
OR srid = 5373
OR srid = 5379
OR srid BETWEEN 5381 AND 5383
OR srid BETWEEN 5387 AND 5389
OR srid = 5391
OR srid = 5393
OR srid = 5396
OR srid = 5451
OR srid BETWEEN 5456 AND 5464
OR srid BETWEEN 5466 AND 5467
OR srid = 5469
OR srid = 5472
OR srid BETWEEN 5479 AND 5482
OR srid = 5487
OR srid BETWEEN 5489 AND 5490
OR srid BETWEEN 5498 AND 5500
OR srid BETWEEN 5513 AND 5514
OR srid BETWEEN 5518 AND 5520
OR srid BETWEEN 5523 AND 5524
OR srid = 5527
OR srid BETWEEN 5530 AND 5539
OR srid = 5544
OR srid = 5546
OR srid BETWEEN 5550 AND 5552
OR srid BETWEEN 5554 AND 5556
OR srid BETWEEN 5558 AND 5559
OR srid BETWEEN 5561 AND 5583
OR srid BETWEEN 5588 AND 5589
OR srid = 5591
OR srid = 5593
OR srid = 5596
OR srid = 5598
OR srid BETWEEN 5623 AND 5625
OR srid BETWEEN 5627 AND 5629
OR srid BETWEEN 5631 AND 5639
OR srid = 5641
OR srid BETWEEN 5643 AND 5644
OR srid = 5646
OR srid BETWEEN 5649 AND 5655
OR srid = 5659
OR srid BETWEEN 5663 AND 5685
OR srid BETWEEN 5698 AND 5700
OR srid BETWEEN 5707 AND 5708
OR srid = 5825
OR srid = 5828
OR srid BETWEEN 5832 AND 5837
OR srid = 5839
OR srid = 5842
OR srid BETWEEN 5844 AND 5858
OR srid BETWEEN 5875 AND 5877
OR srid BETWEEN 5879 AND 5880
OR srid = 5884
OR srid BETWEEN 5886 AND 5887
OR srid = 5890
OR srid BETWEEN 5921 AND 5940
OR srid = 5942
OR srid BETWEEN 5945 AND 5976
OR srid BETWEEN 6050 AND 6125
OR srid BETWEEN 6128 AND 6129
OR srid = 6133
OR srid = 6135
OR srid = 6141
OR srid BETWEEN 6144 AND 6176
OR srid = 6190
OR srid = 6204
OR srid = 6207
OR srid BETWEEN 6210 AND 6211
OR srid = 6307
OR srid = 6309
OR srid BETWEEN 6311 AND 6312
OR srid BETWEEN 6316 AND 6318
OR srid = 6320
OR srid BETWEEN 6322 AND 6323
OR srid = 6325
OR srid BETWEEN 6328 AND 6356
OR srid BETWEEN 6362 AND 6363
OR srid BETWEEN 6365 AND 6372
OR srid BETWEEN 6381 AND 6387
OR srid = 6391
OR srid BETWEEN 6393 AND 6637
OR srid = 6646
OR srid BETWEEN 6649 AND 6666
OR srid BETWEEN 6668 AND 6692
OR srid BETWEEN 6696 AND 6697
OR srid = 6700
OR srid BETWEEN 6703 AND 6704
OR srid BETWEEN 6706 AND 6709
OR srid BETWEEN 6720 AND 6723
OR srid BETWEEN 6732 AND 6738
OR srid = 6781
OR srid BETWEEN 6783 AND 6863
OR srid BETWEEN 6867 AND 6868
OR srid BETWEEN 6870 AND 6871
OR srid BETWEEN 6875 AND 6876
OR srid BETWEEN 6879 AND 6887
OR srid BETWEEN 6892 AND 6894
OR srid = 6915
OR srid = 6917
OR srid BETWEEN 6922 AND 6925
OR srid = 6927
OR srid BETWEEN 6931 AND 6934
OR srid BETWEEN 6956 AND 6959
OR srid = 6962
OR srid = 6978
OR srid BETWEEN 6980 AND 6981
OR srid BETWEEN 6983 AND 6985
OR srid BETWEEN 6987 AND 6988
OR srid BETWEEN 6990 AND 6991
OR srid BETWEEN 6996 AND 6997
OR srid BETWEEN 7005 AND 7007
OR srid = 7035
OR srid = 7037
OR srid = 7039
OR srid = 7041
OR srid BETWEEN 7057 AND 7071
OR srid BETWEEN 7073 AND 7081
OR srid = 7084
OR srid = 7086
OR srid = 7088
OR srid BETWEEN 7109 AND 7128
OR srid BETWEEN 7131 AND 7134
OR srid BETWEEN 7136 AND 7137
OR srid = 7139
OR srid = 7142
OR srid BETWEEN 7257 AND 7371
OR srid BETWEEN 7373 AND 7376
OR srid BETWEEN 7400 AND 7423
OR srid BETWEEN 7528 AND 7645
OR srid = 7656
OR srid = 7658
OR srid = 7660
OR srid = 7662
OR srid = 7664
OR srid = 7677
OR srid = 7679
OR srid = 7681
OR srid BETWEEN 7683 AND 7684
OR srid = 7686
OR srid BETWEEN 7692 AND 7696
OR srid BETWEEN 7755 AND 7787
OR srid = 7789
OR srid BETWEEN 7791 AND 7796
OR srid BETWEEN 7798 AND 7801
OR srid BETWEEN 7803 AND 7805
OR srid = 7815
OR srid BETWEEN 7825 AND 7831
OR srid = 7842
OR srid BETWEEN 7844 AND 7859
OR srid BETWEEN 7877 AND 7879
OR srid BETWEEN 7881 AND 7884
OR srid BETWEEN 7886 AND 7887
OR srid = 7899
OR srid = 7914
OR srid = 7916
OR srid = 7918
OR srid = 7920
OR srid = 7922
OR srid = 7924
OR srid = 7926
OR srid = 7928
OR srid = 7930
OR srid BETWEEN 7954 AND 7956
OR srid BETWEEN 7991 AND 7992
OR srid BETWEEN 8013 AND 8032
OR srid BETWEEN 8035 AND 8036
OR srid BETWEEN 8042 AND 8045
OR srid BETWEEN 8058 AND 8059
OR srid BETWEEN 8065 AND 8068
OR srid BETWEEN 8082 AND 8084
OR srid = 8086
OR srid = 8088
OR srid BETWEEN 8090 AND 8093
OR srid BETWEEN 8095 AND 8173
OR srid = 8177
OR srid BETWEEN 8179 AND 8182
OR srid BETWEEN 8184 AND 8185
OR srid = 8187
OR srid = 8189
OR srid = 8191
OR srid = 8193
OR srid BETWEEN 8196 AND 8198
OR srid BETWEEN 8200 AND 8210
OR srid BETWEEN 8212 AND 8214
OR srid = 8216
OR srid = 8218
OR srid = 8220
OR srid = 8222
OR srid BETWEEN 8224 AND 8227
OR srid = 8230
OR srid BETWEEN 8232 AND 8233
OR srid BETWEEN 8237 AND 8238
OR srid = 8240
OR srid = 8242
OR srid BETWEEN 8246 AND 8247
OR srid BETWEEN 8249 AND 8250
OR srid BETWEEN 8252 AND 8253
OR srid = 8255
OR srid BETWEEN 8311 AND 8350
OR srid BETWEEN 20004 AND 20032
OR srid BETWEEN 20064 AND 20092
OR srid BETWEEN 20135 AND 20138
OR srid BETWEEN 20248 AND 20258
OR srid BETWEEN 20348 AND 20358
OR srid BETWEEN 20436 AND 20440
OR srid = 20499
OR srid BETWEEN 20538 AND 20539
OR srid BETWEEN 20790 AND 20791
OR srid BETWEEN 20822 AND 20824
OR srid BETWEEN 20934 AND 20936
OR srid BETWEEN 21035 AND 21037
OR srid BETWEEN 21095 AND 21097
OR srid = 21100
OR srid BETWEEN 21148 AND 21150
OR srid BETWEEN 21291 AND 21292
OR srid BETWEEN 21413 AND 21423
OR srid BETWEEN 21453 AND 21463
OR srid BETWEEN 21473 AND 21483
OR srid = 21500
OR srid BETWEEN 21780 AND 21782
OR srid BETWEEN 21817 AND 21818
OR srid BETWEEN 21891 AND 21894
OR srid BETWEEN 21896 AND 21899
OR srid BETWEEN 22032 AND 22033
OR srid BETWEEN 22091 AND 22092
OR srid BETWEEN 22171 AND 22177
OR srid BETWEEN 22181 AND 22187
OR srid BETWEEN 22191 AND 22197
OR srid BETWEEN 22234 AND 22236
OR srid = 22275
OR srid = 22277
OR srid = 22279
OR srid = 22281
OR srid = 22283
OR srid = 22285
OR srid = 22287
OR srid = 22289
OR srid = 22291
OR srid = 22293
OR srid = 22300
OR srid = 22332
OR srid BETWEEN 22391 AND 22392
OR srid BETWEEN 22521 AND 22525
OR srid = 22700
OR srid = 22770
OR srid = 22780
OR srid = 22832
OR srid BETWEEN 22991 AND 22994
OR srid BETWEEN 23028 AND 23038
OR srid = 23090
OR srid = 23095
OR srid BETWEEN 23239 AND 23240
OR srid = 23433
OR srid = 23700
OR srid BETWEEN 23830 AND 23853
OR srid BETWEEN 23866 AND 23872
OR srid BETWEEN 23877 AND 23884
OR srid BETWEEN 23886 AND 23894
OR srid BETWEEN 23946 AND 23948
OR srid BETWEEN 24047 AND 24048
OR srid = 24100
OR srid = 24200
OR srid BETWEEN 24305 AND 24306
OR srid BETWEEN 24311 AND 24313
OR srid BETWEEN 24342 AND 24347
OR srid BETWEEN 24370 AND 24383
OR srid = 24500
OR srid BETWEEN 24547 AND 24548
OR srid = 24571
OR srid = 24600
OR srid BETWEEN 24718 AND 24720
OR srid BETWEEN 24817 AND 24821
OR srid BETWEEN 24877 AND 24882
OR srid BETWEEN 24891 AND 24893
OR srid = 25000
OR srid = 25231
OR srid BETWEEN 25391 AND 25395
OR srid = 25700
OR srid BETWEEN 25828 AND 25838
OR srid = 25884
OR srid = 25932
OR srid BETWEEN 26191 AND 26195
OR srid = 26237
OR srid BETWEEN 26331 AND 26332
OR srid BETWEEN 26391 AND 26393
OR srid = 26432
OR srid BETWEEN 26591 AND 26592
OR srid = 26632
OR srid = 26692
OR srid BETWEEN 26701 AND 26722
OR srid BETWEEN 26729 AND 26760
OR srid BETWEEN 26766 AND 26787
OR srid BETWEEN 26791 AND 26799
OR srid BETWEEN 26801 AND 26803
OR srid BETWEEN 26811 AND 26815
OR srid BETWEEN 26819 AND 26826
OR srid BETWEEN 26830 AND 26837
OR srid BETWEEN 26841 AND 26870
OR srid BETWEEN 26891 AND 26899
OR srid BETWEEN 26901 AND 26923
OR srid BETWEEN 26929 AND 26946
OR srid BETWEEN 26948 AND 26998
OR srid BETWEEN 27037 AND 27040
OR srid = 27120
OR srid = 27200
OR srid BETWEEN 27205 AND 27232
OR srid BETWEEN 27258 AND 27260
OR srid BETWEEN 27291 AND 27292
OR srid BETWEEN 27391 AND 27398
OR srid = 27429
OR srid BETWEEN 27492 AND 27493
OR srid = 27500
OR srid BETWEEN 27561 AND 27564
OR srid BETWEEN 27571 AND 27574
OR srid BETWEEN 27581 AND 27584
OR srid BETWEEN 27591 AND 27594
OR srid = 27700
OR srid BETWEEN 28191 AND 28193
OR srid = 28232
OR srid BETWEEN 28348 AND 28358
OR srid BETWEEN 28402 AND 28432
OR srid BETWEEN 28462 AND 28492
OR srid = 28600
OR srid BETWEEN 28991 AND 28992
OR srid BETWEEN 29100 AND 29101
OR srid BETWEEN 29118 AND 29122
OR srid BETWEEN 29168 AND 29172
OR srid BETWEEN 29177 AND 29185
OR srid BETWEEN 29187 AND 29195
OR srid BETWEEN 29220 AND 29221
OR srid = 29333
OR srid = 29371
OR srid = 29373
OR srid = 29375
OR srid = 29377
OR srid = 29379
OR srid = 29381
OR srid = 29383
OR srid = 29385
OR srid BETWEEN 29635 AND 29636
OR srid BETWEEN 29700 AND 29702
OR srid BETWEEN 29738 AND 29739
OR srid BETWEEN 29849 AND 29850
OR srid BETWEEN 29871 AND 29873
OR srid BETWEEN 29900 AND 29903
OR srid BETWEEN 30161 AND 30179
OR srid = 30200
OR srid BETWEEN 30339 AND 30340
OR srid BETWEEN 30491 AND 30494
OR srid BETWEEN 30729 AND 30732
OR srid BETWEEN 30791 AND 30792
OR srid = 30800
OR srid = 31028
OR srid = 31121
OR srid = 31154
OR srid BETWEEN 31170 AND 31171
OR srid BETWEEN 31251 AND 31259
OR srid BETWEEN 31265 AND 31268
OR srid BETWEEN 31275 AND 31279
OR srid BETWEEN 31281 AND 31297
OR srid = 31300
OR srid = 31370
OR srid BETWEEN 31461 AND 31469
OR srid BETWEEN 31528 AND 31529
OR srid = 31600
OR srid = 31700
OR srid BETWEEN 31838 AND 31839
OR srid BETWEEN 31900 AND 31901
OR srid BETWEEN 31965 AND 32003
OR srid BETWEEN 32005 AND 32031
OR srid BETWEEN 32033 AND 32058
OR srid BETWEEN 32061 AND 32062
OR srid BETWEEN 32064 AND 32067
OR srid BETWEEN 32074 AND 32077
OR srid BETWEEN 32081 AND 32086
OR srid BETWEEN 32098 AND 32100
OR srid = 32104
OR srid BETWEEN 32107 AND 32130
OR srid BETWEEN 32133 AND 32158
OR srid = 32161
OR srid BETWEEN 32164 AND 32167
OR srid BETWEEN 32180 AND 32199
OR srid BETWEEN 32201 AND 32260
OR srid BETWEEN 32301 AND 32360
OR srid BETWEEN 32401 AND 32460
OR srid BETWEEN 32501 AND 32560
OR srid BETWEEN 32601 AND 32667
OR srid BETWEEN 32701 AND 32761
OR srid = 32766
OR srid = 900913
)"}````
`````

Comment: One thing right from the beginning, test setup or not: **do not use the `postgres` DB** for anything else than the initial connection; it's the systems maintenance DB and shouldn't get altered! Better create a new DB and add the extension there (**PostGIS is not installed globally, but is enabled for the selected DB only**). What does `SELECT postgis_full_version();` return?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In the current test-db ```SELECT postgis_full_version();``` returns
```POSTGIS="2.5.3 r17699" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125" PROJ="Rel. 6.2.0, September 1st, 2019" GDAL="GDAL 3.0.1, released 2019/06/28" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" TOPOLOGY RASTER```

Comment: Okay, and can you `SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOEMETRY(POINT, 4326);`?

Comment: Ran: ```SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326);```
Got: ```SQL-Fehler [22023]: ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)```

Comment: Haha, yeah sorry, my mistake; it's a habit to write out the full type cast. PostGIS is installed and ready to use! Run `SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY` instead, just to make that point... now, since all is good, where exactly did you get stuck when writing that question??

Comment: As I said, I cannot add PostGIS data types to my tables.

Comment: How are you attempting to add those types? What's the error message? `CREATE TABLE spatial_test (uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326));` does not work?

Comment: Thanks, yes that works. I also can add a geometry column to an existing table, e.g. by using ```ALTER TABLE fundplaetze ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point,4326);```. The PostGIS extension was apparently working all the time. The question was just, if you can also add geometry columns in the graphical interface of DBeaver, which is apparently not the case. I will edit the question to "How to check if PostGIS extension is installed and working". Could you please post your help as an answer.

Comment: Hm...not sure how this could be an answer. And if your question was indeed *'How to work with PostGIS in the DBeaver UI'* then I did not answer anything, and you might want to ask specifically (although that question would not 100% fit on the GIS.SE board). I will add an answer with some ways to check for the correct installation...but I think this will make this question a duplicate of many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To summarize the comments as an answer:*

First off, the `postgres` DB is used as the systems maintenance DB and should not be used in other ways than manual maintenance and recovery.

Always create a separate DB, even for testing purposes!

---

**To check the PostGIS installation**, run

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

which, if correctly installed, should return sth. like (citing your own specs):

> POSTGIS="2.5.3 r17699" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125" PROJ="Rel. 6.2.0, September 1st, 2019" GDAL="GDAL 3.0.1, released 2019/06/28" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" TOPOLOGY RASTER

---

After that, using the `GEOMETRY` data type in your tables should be working as expected, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE spatial_test (
  uid  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)
);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)
;
```

and the `ST` functions and PostGIS type casts should be available, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(
         ST_SetSRID('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 4326),
         1
       ) AS geom
;
```

---

However, after clarifying your question in the comments: if the PostGS types are available through the *DBeaver* UI I don't know.

**Update:**

*DBeaver* 6.3.0 doesn't add PostGIS types to the selection when creating a new column. It allows to manually specify (type in) `geometry`, but it is best practice to explicitly define the geometry type, e.g. `GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)` whenever possible. It seems the better option is to issue the respective DDL manually.